# How to supress children from invoking parent's event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-controls, awesomium

I'm creating simple touch-based user comtol web browser. I'm using `ManipulationDelta` event to pan, zoom-in, zoom-out etc. The browser (Awesomium WebControl) is placed inside a grid of control. When I try to scroll page whole browser moves. How to supress invoking parent's event by childen?
I've set userinput type to `ViewInput.Mouse` because I want to handle touch by myself.

XAML:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:awe="http://schemas.awesomium.com/winfx" x:Name="_control" x:Class="WebControlTouch.WebBrowser" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="497" Height="323.333">
    <Grid TouchDown="_mainGrid_TouchDown" x:Name="_mainGrid" Background="Honeydew" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,-66,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="466*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="84*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="220*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <awe:WebControl TouchDown="_browser_TouchDown"  Visibility="Visible" LoadingFrameFailed="_browser_LoadingFrameFailed" LoadingFrameComplete="_browser_LoadingFrameComplete" LoadingFrame="_browser_LoadingFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="_browser" AddressChanged="_browser_AddressChanged" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,1,0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="_addressBar" Height="43" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="_goButton" Grid.Row="0" TouchDown="Button_TouchDown" Content="Go!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="131,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.164,0.514" Height="43" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button TouchDown="Btn_back" x:Name="_btnBack" Content="Back" Click="Btn_back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="276,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Height="20"/>
        <Button TouchDown="_btn_forward" x:Name="_btnForward" Content="Forward" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="_btn_forward" Grid.Column="1" Height="20"/>
        <Label x:Name="_Status" Content="Ready" Margin="277,42,130,16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Height="26"/>
        <Button x:Name="_exitButton" Content="Exit!" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" TouchDown="_exitButton_TouchDown"/>
        <Button x:Name="_temp" Content="Scroll" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="459.312,10.04,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="_tempClick"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you want some event(s) to stop bubbling (up) the control hierarchy. 
All you should usually need to do is marked the event as handled (the event instance you get in your event handler):

```
e.Handled = true;
```

In your case should be something like:

```
private void _browser_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{ 
    //...
    e.Handled = true;
    //...
}
```

Comment: You are saving my ass!